# Is it acceptable to repeat the same h1 tag for desktop and mobile browsers in a responsive site?

Tags: seo, html, responsive-webdesign

I have a website with a page that has a video as the main content. It uses a responsive design layout that requires the `<h1>` tag (with the same text) to be used in two different places: one for desktop browsers and one for mobile browsers.

I will have to hide the mobile version of the `<h1>` tag for desktop browsers, and hide the desktop `<h1>` tag for mobile versions.

Will this present any problems with respect to SEO or otherwise?

Or what if I make the second header a simple `<div>` or `<p>` tag instead of an `<h1>` tag, and apply CSS accordingly - would that be acceptable then?

Comment: There is no rule against using multiple H1 tags, however, Google warns against it saying that there really should only be one. They have a point, but Google does not make the rules- the community does. If there is a way to satisfy your requirements and still only have one H1 tag without hiding content, that is what I recommend. For a more complete and technical response, I leave that to someone who may have more ideas for you to answer.

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc what if I use the second one as div instead of h1 ? Will it harm SEO because the same sentence is repeating ?

Comment: Whats the difference between the desktop version of H1 and the Mobile...Please add that to your question.

Comment: I am not sure. I would *not* think it would be enough to get a penalty. But does it help? I am not sure. I know that it would be work, and I do not know the system you are using, if it is at all possible to make one sentence slightly different from the other, I would go for that. I would almost take two marketing techniques to engage/motivate the user. It sounds like your in a tough spot. I write my own CMS so for me it is an easy task. I would almost bet you would be okay.

Comment: @bybe There is no difference in the text. Only difference is one is visible in desktop and another in mobile. I am doing this because the layout of the site needs this.

Comment: @closetnoc I will try that(making one sentence slightly different from another). Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how much this may help, but I have some examples of marketing approaches http://www.closetnoc.org/?i=conversion-internet-marketing and on some of the other pages too. It may help spark some ideas. Please forgive the fact that I am not good at making pretty websites! I am not so pretty myself so it balances out. I specialize in data automation.

Comment: @John Conde I request you to revise the duplicate tag on my question. The question is different because here I am talking about putting the same h1 tag in two places to achieve the goals of responsive design. The other question is about putting <b>Different</b> h1 tags in different places. Thanks

Comment: @SandeshYadav I edited the question based on your comments above and re-opened it. Responsive design is focused on using the same content (e.g., the same `h1` tag) to display to both desktop and mobile browsers, instead of duplicating content between the two. If that's still necessary for some reason though, you should be fine since it's not duplicate content _between_ pages, and Google understands responsive designs can result in some amount of content being duplicated on the same page (often with headers, navigation, footers, etc...).

Comment: Sandesh Yadav care to explain the layout or give an example as I'm sure you're have several solutions based on what you need.

Comment: @bybe the layout is in such a way that if I don't repeat the h1 tag, I will have to put everything as absolute positioning for mobile device.

Comment: Well without seeing it or illustrating I can't help since you can use absolute positions on mobile and relative on desktop using media queries without using double titles, for extended titles you can use span within H1 and use display:none again using media queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using multiple H1 tags *is* valid in HTML 5, as long as each is inside a `<section>` element (except for the first H1 on the page which does not need a specific wrapper).

For SEO, [Google has confirmed](https://youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM) that multiple H1 tags are fine.

However, you ought to take another look at your responsive layout, as requiring an H1 in two different places seems strange to me. It's almost certainly possible that you can achieve two different layouts with the same HTML in the same places. Perhaps ask a question on Stack Overflow with your specific scenario, you are bound to get a good answer.

Comment: I haven't used it yet myself, but it looks like `grid-template-areas` is a slick solution for re-arranging layouts with CSS in a responsive design that doesn't require any duplication of sections.  See https://tomduffytech.com/responsive-layout/  It appears to be supported in all recent major browsers https://caniuse.com/?search=grid-template-areas (93.5% of users support it).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Same thing can be achieved with flexbox using `order` property.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple H1 tags is valid in HTML 5, as long as each is inside a  element (except for the first H1 on the page which does not need a specific wrapper).

Comment: This question is tagged "SEO" which implies they are asking if it is acceptable to search engines.   Its good to know that the standards would allow it, but do you any SEO experience regarding it?

Comment: This is not true (anymore), the use of multiple h1 in html 5 (section) elements once was in the spec, later removed. See https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/changes.html#features-removed.